# Есть ли способы обратить миграцию change_column?

Tags: база-данных, ruby-on-rails, миграция

1) Создал миграцию

```
def change
  change_column :price_items, :weight, :float, default: 2
end
```

2) узнал что `change_column` необратима

Но нужно от нее избавиться. Ее нет в продакшн, вариант просто удалить ее прокатит? в dev-базе это несущественное изменение.

Comment: А какой тип столбца `price_items.weight` был до выполнения миграции?

Comment: :float, я только значение по умолчанию добавил.

Comment: Тогда если миграция попадает в продакшен, в down-методе миграции можно было бы прописать change_column с исходным default-значением и выполнить `rake db:rollback` или просто сделать еще одну миграцию change_column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если миграция не выкатывалась в продакшен и она не зарегистрирована в таблице `schema_migrations` продакшен базы данных, **да вы можете просто удалить** ее и запушить изменения в репозиторий.

1) В develompment окружении будет достаточно воссоздать базу данных при помощи следующей команды

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

Или еще более короткий вариант

```
rake db:reset
```

2) Если нужна точная копия продакшен базы данных, снять дамп с прода и развернуть его локально средствами используемой вами базы данных.

Comment: Вообще, я подумал что можно сделать еще одну миграцию типа `change_column :price_items, :weight, :float` (т.е. просто убрал значение по умолчанию), но этот вариант не сработал.

Comment: Хорошо бы явно задавать defalut-значение, даже если это NULL `change_column :price_items, :weight, :float, default: nil`

Comment: в таком случае `change_column :price_items, :weight, :float == change_column :price_items, :weight, :float, default: nil`?

Comment: Первый случай не меняет значение `default`, оставляя старое. Вот если вы добавляете столбец при помощи `add_column`, тогда, да, ключ `default` получает значение `nil`, а столбец значение по умолчанию `NULL`.